# Issue when dragging elements when using Dragula

Tags: javascript, html, css, dragula

I'm still working on a school project due soon and I've made things work since my last question. I went for the Dragula library and this worked fine. If you test my code you'll see that when you drag the hexagon around the chils buttons and text field falls outside the hexagon while dragging and get into the correct position again when I drop the hexagon. How to avoid the elements from falling out of the hexagon while dragging them?

Here is the link to the gitHub that you can clone and test with:

https://github.com/Martinius222/ProsjektMaster

this is an ongoing project so different files in the project but
the relevant files are the index.html style.css dragula.js (library) to test.

I've tried to fiddle around with the HTML and CSS of hexagons and child buttons without luck. I suspect there is a problem with the JavaScript.

There's a lot of code, but I've posted a link to the gitHub for the whole project. Beneath is the HTML and CSS though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IdeaComb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dragula.css">

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dragula.js"></script>

    <nav></nav>
    <div id="sidebar">

        <div id="options"></div>
        <div id="listField"></div>
        <div id="generator">
            <div id="generatorOptions">
                <button id="newCombBtn">+</button>
            </div>
            <div id="generatorField">

            </div>



        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="workspace">

        <div class="rows" id="row1">

            <div id="1x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x3" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="1x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="rows" id="row2">

            <div id="2x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x3" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="2x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="rows" id="row3">

            <div id="3x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x3" class="cont">
                <div class="hexagon">
                    <div id="likebtn">+</div>
                    <div id="deletebtn">x</div>
                    <input type="" name="" placeholder="Test">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="3x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="3x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>  

        <div class="rows" id="row4">

            <div id="4x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x3" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="4x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="rows" id="row5">

            <div id="5x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x3" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="5x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="rows" id="row6">

            <div id="6x1" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x2" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x3" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x4" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x5" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x6" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x7" class="cont"></div>
            <div id="6x8" class="cont"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<script>
dragula([document.getElementById("generatorField"), document.getElementById("1x1"), document.getElementById("1x2"), document.getElementById("1x3"), document.getElementById("1x4"), document.getElementById("1x5"),document.getElementById("1x6"), document.getElementById("1x7"), document.getElementById("1x8"), document.getElementById("2x1"), document.getElementById("2x2"), document.getElementById("2x3"), document.getElementById("2x4"), document.getElementById("2x5"), document.getElementById("2x6"), document.getElementById("2x7"), document.getElementById("2x8"), document.getElementById("3x1"), document.getElementById("3x2"), document.getElementById("3x3"), document.getElementById("3x4"), document.getElementById("3x5"), document.getElementById("3x6"), document.getElementById("3x7"), document.getElementById("3x8"), document.getElementById("4x1"), document.getElementById("4x2"), document.getElementById("4x3"), document.getElementById("4x4"), document.getElementById("4x5"), document.getElementById("4x6"), document.getElementById("4x7"), document.getElementById("4x8"), document.getElementById("5x1"), document.getElementById("5x2"), document.getElementById("5x3"), document.getElementById("5x4"), document.getElementById("5x5"), document.getElementById("5x6"), document.getElementById("5x7"), document.getElementById("5x8"), document.getElementById("6x1"), document.getElementById("6x2"), document.getElementById("6x3"), document.getElementById("6x4"), document.getElementById("6x5"), document.getElementById("6x6"), document.getElementById("6x7"), document.getElementById("6x8")],  {
revertOnSpill: true
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5em;
    background-color: #ebc645;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #463e20;
}

#options {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    height: 4em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 1em auto 0 auto; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 

}

#listField {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    height: 30em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 1em auto 0 auto; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}

#generator {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 95%;
    height: 12em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 1em auto 0 auto; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 9; 
}

#generatorOptions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 17%;
    height: 100%;

}

#generatorField {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 83%;
    height: 100%;

}

#newCombBtn {
    margin-top: .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    top: -5em;
    left: -8em;
    width: 35px;
    height: 37px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ebc645;
    z-index: 10;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 17%;
    height: 50em;
    margin: 1em 4px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ebc645;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #463e20;
}

#workspace {

display: inline-block;
width: 82%;
height: 30em;
margin: 0;
float: left;

}


#row2 {
position: relative;
top: -3.8em;
left: 4.3em;

}

#row3 {
position: relative;
top: -7.6em;

}

#row4 {
position: relative;
top: -11.4em;
left: 4.3em;

}

#row5 {
position: relative;
top: -15.2em;

}

#row6 {
position: relative;
top: -19em;
left: 4.3em;

}



.cont {
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    width:11%;
    height: 11em;
    /*background-color: black;*/
    background-color: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}

/*.cont > .box {

    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 2px lightblue;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: grab;
}*/

/*.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 133.77px; 
  height: 77.23px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 38.62px 0;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 66.885px solid transparent;
  border-right: 66.885px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 38.62px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 38.62px solid #64C7CC;
}*/

.cont > .hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 133.77px; 
  height: 77.23px;
  background-color: #ebc645;
  margin: 38.62px 0;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;


}

.cont > .hexagon:before,
.cont > .hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 66.885px solid transparent;
  border-right: 66.885px solid transparent;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cont > .hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 38.62px solid #ebc645;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cont > .hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 38.62px solid #ebc645;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cont > .hexagon > #likebtn {
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 7em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;

}

.cont > .hexagon > #deletebtn {
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;

}

/*Styling for generated hexagon inside generator div*/

#generatorField > .hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; 
  height: 86.60px;
  background-color: #ebc645;
  margin: 43.30px 0;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;


}

#generatorField > .hexagon:before,
#generatorField > .hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}

#generatorField > .hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 43.30px solid #ebc645;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}

#generatorField > .hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 43.30px solid #ebc645;
  cursor: grab;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```
//Javascript for "New Comb" generator in the bottom left

document.getElementById("newCombBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var btn = document.createElement("div");
    btn.classList.add("hexagon");
    document.getElementById("generatorField").appendChild(btn);
});
```

Again, this might be an issue with the Dragula library. But the child elements of the hexagon divs drop out of the hexagons when dragging